# Inside shell script: write Python output to file works from terminal, "Input stream is empty" when running from launchd

Tags: macos, shell, python-2.7, launchd, launch-agent

I wrote a short shell script to write the contents of an Evernote note to a file with Geeknote, which runs under python:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python /Users/me/Git/geeknote/geeknote.py find --search "Hobbies To Do" > /dev/null
/usr/bin/python -u /Users/me/Git/geeknote/geeknote.py show "Hobbies To Do" | tee /Users/me/Programming/output.txt
```

The script works fine when I run it from terminal (it writes the output of the second python command to output.txt), although ideally I'd like the script to run periodically on its own. So I tried creating a .plist/LaunchAgent to run the script, but when I do that the only thing that gets written to output.txt is `Input stream is empty`...can't figure out why. Right now my .plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.me.geektoolcron</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/me/Programming/script.sh</string>
  </array>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>10</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the second python command with something like `echo a` or replacing tee with a redirection. A script like this worked for me with the same plist:

```
#!/bin/bash

date | tee /tmp/f
```

launchd also supports directing stdout to a file:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/me/Programming/output.txt</string>
```

Comment: Tried replacing with a redirection, didn't work. It seems that whatever python outputs when this is run from the terminal isn't captured when running through the plist